# Collation change utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8mb4_general_ci

Tags: mysql, database, collation, utf8mb4

For my databases, I used `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` with `utf8mb4` character set as a default. This was a mistake and the folks who are using the databases I created are complaining about the collation. I need to convert it to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. Am I able to get away with just changing the DB using an alter statement such as:

```
ALTER DATABASE `#{database}` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Or, will I need to change each individual table and deal with columns even though the charset is the same between the two collations? I can't seem to find definitive answers on this... I'm using MySQL 5.7.2x .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is better than either of the collations you mentioned.

Why are they complaining?  Perhaps `JOINs` are failing to use indexes.  I would argue with them that the old tables should be changed.

`ALTER DATABASE` only sets up defaults for future tables.  It will *not* do what you need.

`ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` for each table is needed.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes for a similar `ALTER`.  It provides a way to automatically generate all the `ALTERs`.

Comment: If no one is connected to the DB, does this look safe? - `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` ,`ALTER TABLE #{table} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci` , 
    `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` for each of the tables within the DB that are `BASE TABLES` ?